# Store and read string with newline from Config::Simple config file

Tags: perl, config, newline

I would like to load a string with newlines from a configuration file. The script I am modifying uses the [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple) module.

Here's a MWE:

```
# file: script.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;

# read config file
my $cfg = new Config::Simple('config.cfg');
my %config = $cfg->vars();
# read parameter 'string'
my $var = $config{"string"};

print($var);
```

This works fine for 'normal' strings in `config.cfg`:

```
# file: config.cfg

string: "One Two Three"
```

Now I want to store a string with newlines in the parameter `string`. Since `Config::Simple` requires each parameter to be on a single line (i.e. does not support multi-line parameters), I tried the following

```
# file: config.cfg

string: "One \nTwo \nThree"
```

but it seems that `Config::Simple` strips the `\` character, because `$var` becomes

```
One nTwo nThree
```

Is there a good way to do this with `Config::Simple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the source code for `Config::Simple`, you see that it calls `parse_line` from [Text::ParseWords](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords) which will:

> remove all quotes and backslashes that are not themselves
> backslash-escaped

I can't see a way to modify the behavior of `Config::Simple`, but one option is to change your config file to backslash the backslashes:

```
string: "One \\nTwo \\nThree"
```

This outputs:

```
One \nTwo \nThree
```

Interestingly, if you use the `param()` method instead of the `vars()` method, you get a different output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;

my $cfg = new Config::Simple('config.cfg');
my $var = $cfg->param('string');
print "$var\n";
```

Output:

```
One 
Two 
Three
```

Comment: Great, this made me find the solution. Add a replacement to your answer, and I have exactly what I needed. I added an answer with the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem with the help of @toolic's answer:

When I change the config file to include double backslashes, I get the characters `\n` in `$var`:

```
# file: config.cfg

string: "One \\nTwo \\nThree"
```

The only thing that's left to do is to replace the two characters `\n` with an actual newline character:

```
# file: script.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;

# read config file
my $cfg = new Config::Simple('config.cfg');
my %config = $cfg->vars();
# read parameter 'string' and regex-replace '\\n' with '\n'
my $var = $config{"string"} =~ s/\\n/\n/gr;

print($var);
```

This gives me

```
One
Two
Three
```

as I wanted.

*EDIT*: it seems that the replacement is only necessary when using `Config::Simple`'s hash method of accessing the values via `.vars()`. In the method `param()` the replacement is actually already implemented within `Config::Simple` but only there (bug in v4.59, author has been notified). So either use `param()` or replace `\n` as described in this answer.